# How to convert ESRI shapefile format using QGIS or python gdal library to extract lat lon

Tags: python, esri, qgis

I have files in ESRI Shapefile format. May I know how can I use QGIS or python gdal library to extract the latitude and longitude? I have installed QGIS and add layer of the shapefile into it, I can view the (lat, long) on the map but I do not know how to extract the (lat,long) out.. Do advice me how to extract the (lat,long) out. TQ

Comment: What do you mean by extracting, convert to CSV/text file? Do you have a Shapefile with point coordinates or is it other geometries?

Comment: Yes to convert to text file. The shapefile is with coordinates.

Comment: Did any of proposed solutions solve your problems? Then please mark that answer as selected for future visitors and in orderd to close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Right click your layer, select "Save As". The dialog "Save vector layer as..." will open. Select the following options:

Format: Comma Separated Value [CSV]
File name: Select a file name
CRS: EPSG:4326, WGS84

In the lower part, expand "Select fields to export" and click "Deselect All" if you just want the coordinates, or check the available items (columns from the attribute table) if you need place names, etc. By choosing WGS84 as the output CRS you'll receive your coordinates in decimal degrees (latitude, longitude).

[image: Screenshot for 'Save vector layer as']

Example output:

```
X,Y
12.4533865449718,41.9032821799601
12.4417701578001,43.936095834768
9.51666947290727,47.1337237742936
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with python, you don't need gdal for that. I find geopandas (with Shapely) a much simpler library for working with shapefiles. Though at first it might take a few minutes longer than clicking through QGIS interface, learning how to manipulate shapefiles in Python is very powerful knowledge in a long run. Here is a sample of your task, performed with python:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# read shapefile (attributes and geometry) into geodataframe
shp = gpd.read_file("sample_shapefile.shp")

# convert "geometry" field into separate X and Y fields
shp["X"]=shp["geometry"].apply(lambda geom: geom.x)
shp["Y"]=shp["geometry"].apply(lambda geom: geom.y)

#save X,Y into csv file
shp[["X","Y"]].to_csv("coords.csv",header=True,index=False,sep=",")
```

Whick will produce the desired output in coords.csv:

```
X,Y
425070.0,80330.0
408390.0,81150.0
405370.0,85860.0
410880.0,82850.0
415310.0,80630.0
418610.0,80350.0
```